# Alpine.js global store data is not injected

Tags: alpine.js

Is my first approach to alpine, but I have some problems.
Usually when I use alpine data everything is conteinerized in the same parent div

```html
<div x-data="hello">
    <div x-show="hello></div>
</div>
```

In my case I need to split the divs to handle some x-show proprierties in this way:

```html
<div x-data="hello"></div>
<div x-show="hello></div>
```

So I tried to use the Alpine.Store to get global data, the problem is that the mobile menu never appear, olso watching with the alpine js devtools in the mobile menu div the `openMobileMenu` data is not injected, instead on the navbar I see the `openMobileMenu` changing.

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
document.addEventListener('alpine:init', () => {
  Alpine.store('mobileMenu', {
    openMobileMenu: false,

    toggleMobileMenu() {
                  this.openMobileMenu = ! this.openMobileMenu;
              },
  })
})
</script>

<header>
  <!-- Navbar goes here -->
  <nav class="bg-gray-800">
    <div class="max-w-6xl mx-auto px-4">
      <div class="flex justify-between">
        <div class="self-center">
        //some stuff
        <!-- Mobile menu button -->
        <div x-data class="md:hidden flex items-center h-14">
          <button class="outline-none mobile-menu-button" @click="$store.mobileMenu.toggleMobileMenu">
            <svg class="" fill="none" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor">
              <path d="M4 6h16M4 12h16M4 18h16"></path>
            </svg>
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- mobile menu -->
    <div x-data x-show="$store.mobileMenu.openMobileMenu">
      <ul class="">
        <li><a href="/dome" class="">Dome</a></li>
        <li><a href="/switch" class=">Switch</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
</header>
```

The only way I found to make it work is moving the data in the header, but I would like why this way is not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call `toggleMobileMenu()` on click, so add the missing `()`: `@click="$store.mobileMenu.toggleMobileMenu()"`

```html
<script defer src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/alpinejs@3.x.x/dist/cdn.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
document.addEventListener('alpine:init', () => {
  Alpine.store('mobileMenu', {
    openMobileMenu: false,

    toggleMobileMenu() {
                  this.openMobileMenu = ! this.openMobileMenu;
              },
  })
})
</script>
<header>
  <!-- Navbar goes here -->
  <nav class="bg-gray-800">
    <div class="max-w-6xl mx-auto px-4">
      <div class="flex justify-between">
        <div class="self-center">
        <!-- Mobile menu button -->
        <div x-data class="md:hidden flex items-center h-14">
          <button class="outline-none mobile-menu-button" @click="$store.mobileMenu.toggleMobileMenu()">
            <svg class="" fill="none" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor">
              <path d="M4 6h16M4 12h16M4 18h16"></path>
            </svg>
            Toggle menu
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- mobile menu -->
    <div x-data x-show="$store.mobileMenu.openMobileMenu">
      <ul class="">
        <li><a href="/dome" class="">Dome</a></li>
        <li><a href="/switch" class="">Switch</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
</header>
```